# flask-sqlalchemy field start with a number

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I define a table with `flask-sqlalchemy`. A special field start with a number, as below:

`class Foo(db.Model):
    6F78 = db.Column(db.String(10))`

The field name `6F78` causes `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.But the field name can't modify to another name, as it is constant.
So, what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python identifiers can't start with a number, which is why you can't create a member on an object name `6F78`.

You can however point your representation of that column in your code to a column in the database of a different label, try this:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    my_column_name_6F78 = db.Column( "6F78", db.String() )
```

Then in code you refer to `my_column_name_6F78` instead of `6F78`.  If course you could chose a more concise name for the column in your code, like `c6F78`.